# Plumbing Vent - Proper service?

Tags: plumbing, venting

Which professional should I call to correct a plumbing venting drip issue that is in the attic?

I have an older home, where the newer plumbing vent is coupled the older after entering through the roof. The coupling is made with the old roof's vent pipe flashing and not too surprisingly leaks.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: You are going to need a roofing specialist to come and replace the flashing so the pipe has a snug fit around the pipe.  This is a pretty easy job if you have asphalt shingles.

Option 2: I had the same issue and fixed it by getting some roofing caulk and sealing the gaps around the pipe

Good Luck!